# render('django.contrib.auth.views.login') pointing to different url than {% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}

Tags: python, django

I'm on Django 1.5.1 using the default implementation of the Django authentication system.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'flowcharts',
    'south',
    'helpdesk',
)
```

Here is the template located in registration/login:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
<td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
<td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

and in my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' , {'next_page': '/accounts/login/'}),
)
```

The form action is mapping to '/helpdesk/login/'

But when I run render('django.contrib.auth.views.login') in the python shell I get '/accounts/login/' , which is the URL that I want the form pointing to. Let me know if any other information is needed about the project.

Comment: Can you try <form method="post" action="{% url login %}">

Comment: Here's the source code for 
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}"> :   

<form method="post" action="/helpdesk/login/">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use django authentication system:

Have this in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
)
```

In your registration/login.html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url login %}">
```

You want to provide a next_url in the logout, so whenever you want to call logout:

```
<a href="{% url logout %}?next=/accounts/login/">Logout</a>
```

Check line 191 of the link you pointed. They name `/helpdesk/login/` as `login` and so your `{% url login %}` points to `/helpdesk/login`.

You must be having `url(r'^helpdesk/', include('helpdesk.urls'))` before `url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` in your `urls.py`. Change the order of these two urls.

Comment: The form is still displaying as 
    <form method="post" action="/helpdesk/login/">

Comment: Can you check your urls.py for helpdesk?

Answer (score -1):

this is what im using and getting it correct

```
<li><a href="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a></li>
```

so i guess you have to remove the single quotes

Comment: can you try giving the url pattern a name and like url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',name="some_name"), and use that name ?

Comment: Weird... I'm getting a 400 Bad Request. I've never gotten that before