# How to properly get url for the login view in template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a small problem with figuring out how `{% url 'something' %}` works in django templates.

When I run my website in debug mode, I see this in stdout:

```
web_1 | [21/Dec/2015 11:29:45] "GET /accounts/profile HTTP/1.1" 302 0
web_1 | /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py:499: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Reversing by dotted path is deprecated (django.contrib.auth.views.login).
web_1 |   url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
web_1 |
```

The /accounts/profile maps to a template, and the only place in this template that mentions `django.contrib.auth.views.login` is the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout' %}?next={% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">Log out</a>
```

So, I guess that for some reason this is not the proper way to use {% url %} command. What is the proper way? How to get rid of this warning?

Here are my urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/profile', views.profile_view),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy(views.profile_view)))
]
```

Comment: in the template use the name of the url entry (as defined in `urls.py`) i.e. `<a href="{% url 'optional_template_namespace:entry_name' %}">Log out</a>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the *name* of the url, instead of its dotted path.

In this case, you have included the url patterns from `django.contrib.auth.urls`. If you look at [that urls file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d7580e286ac9c48e410d59281720205d6f5dda10/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L10), you can see that the name of the views are `login` and `logout`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    ...
]
```

Therefore, change your link to:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={% url 'login' %}">Log out</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at 
[urls.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py)

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
```

you can refer the name when using url

```
{% url 'login' %}
```

and

```
{% url 'logout' %}
```

or if you need to logout with next then

```
<a href="{% url logout %}?next=/accounts/login/">Logout</a>
```

Check out this post
['django.contrib.auth.views.login'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248490/renderdjango-contrib-auth-views-login-pointing-to-different-url-than-url)

Answer (score 0):

In `urls.py` add the name to each relevant entry (not the the ones which include other definitions, as the name would be ignored)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/profile', views.profile_view, name='acc_profile'),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy(views.profile_view)), name='home')
]
```

Then in the templates use the name of the url entry, as defined above i.e.

```
<a href="{% url 'optional_template_namespace:entry_name' %}">The link text</a>
```

In the given case, the `login` and `logout` urls come from the standard `django.contrib.auth.urls` and their name is simple enough (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/) for further info)

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={% url 'login' %}">Log out</a>
```