# Why do I get RemovedInDjango110Warning when redirecting to log in page lite this?

Tags: django, django-views

For my index page I want to show one page if the user is logged in and redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in. I do this with the following view code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

def index(request):
    if not request.user is None and request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('foo/index.html')
    else :
        return redirect(login)
```

However I get the following warning:

```
RemovedInDjango110Warning: Reversing by dotted path is deprecated (django.contrib.auth.views.login)
```

All I have found on the topic is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394900/how-to-properly-get-url-for-the-login-view-in-template) but although it seems vaguely related I can't understand how to apply it to my problem.
What does "Reversing by dotted path" mean? And where do I do it and how should it be done instead?

---

EDIT: I thought those lines where the problem but seems to not be the case. So the question is still similar but more general:

What does "Reversing by dotted path" mean? How do I figure out where I do it? And what should be done instead?

Comment: Turns out I was doing similar things at more locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the 'Reversing by dotted path is deprecated' message is a bit confusing in this case.

Say you have:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login-page'),
```

The deprecation warning is saying that you should use the url name `'login-page'` instead of the dotted path, `'django.contrib.auth.views.login'` when you reverse urls.

In your case, you are reversing urls when you use the `redirect` shortcut. When you do

```
    return redirect(login)
```

the callable login is converted to a string `'django.contrib.auth.views.login'` and the string is reversed, triggering the warning.

You can stop the warning by changing that line to:

```
    return redirect('login-page')
```

You may then be able to remove `from django.contrib.auth.views import login` if it is not used anywhere else.

Note that the idiomatic way to write your view would be to use `login_required` and `render`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'foo/index.html')
```

Comment: Aha, going from using the actual view into using a hard-coded string seemed weird but the login_required approach is even better so don't need to care about that :)